# Retornar uma instância da mesma classe em static function

Tags: php, classes, métodos-estáticos

Eu estou tentando retornar uma instancia da mesma classe em funções estáticas, por exemplo, no código abaixo, funciona normal:

```
class Router
{
    private $name;

    public function get()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function name($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

E pra usar:

```
$router = new Router();
$router->get()->name('string');
```

Mas quando eu tento com `static function`, não acontece nada.

```
class Router
{
    private static $name;

    public static function get()
    {
        return self::class;
    }

    public static function name($name) {
        self::$name = $name;
    }
}
```

E pra usar:

```
Router::get()->name('string');
```

Com `static` recebo de retorno:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function name()

Comment: Não dá para saber o que pretendia que ocorresse, ambos fazem nada, até porque é isso que essas classes fazem. https://ideone.com/OoCL0n De qualquer forma não faz muito sentido criar um código assim, teria que explicar melhor onde quer chegar.

Comment: @Maniero, editei a pergunta, vê se você consegue entender.

Comment: A pergunta mudou completamente, mas o texto ainda trata de parte da forma antiga e ficou confusa, mas vou responder assim mesmo porque acho que dá para entender apesar de estar mal formulado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para chamar membros estáticos sempre deve usar `::`, não basta usar só em um lugar, então o código correto seria:

```
Router::get()::name('string');
```

Obviamente é possível retornar a própria classe em um método estático e usar a chamada do jeito que escreveu. Mas aí o método a ser chamado de ser de instância e não estático. É tudo casado, a forma como declara o método determina a forma como deve chamá-lo.

```
class Router {
    private static $name;

    public static function get() {
        return $this;
    }

    public function name($name) {
        self::$name = $name;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/GetInstanceToStatic.php).

Mas um código assim não faz sentido.

Comment: Então, eu estava olhando o Laravel, eles usam algo parecido com: `Route::get()->name();`. Pra eu fazer isso meu método `name` não poderia ser `static` ? Você me recomenda alguma leitura sobre as práticas sobre isso ? Na minha visão eu não acho certo misturar tudo.

Comment: Só pra constar aqui, dessa maneira também não funcionou, da forma sem ser static é só retornar `$this`, com static não funciona :/

Comment: Mineiro, `return new static;` pra eu poder acessar os métodos da classe; Deu certo agora. Obrigado

Comment: `Route::get()` no seu exemplo precisa retornar uma instância, não um self::class

Comment: @gmsantos, no caso `return new static;` né?

Comment: O `get()` sim, o `name()` não. Claro que retornando ´$this" não dá erro, respondi em cima do que postou. Recomendo um estudo estruturado e não ficar tentando adivinhar como as coisas são. Recomendo começar pelos fundamentos antes de praticar (a prática é boa quando se sabe o que está fazendo). Mas hoje quase ninguém quer fazer isso e por isso a maioria que está começando está iludida que está aprendendo programar porque consegue fazer algumas coisas. Você parece que pelo menos está procurando entender o que se passa, mas precisa estruturar isso. Procure livros.Não indico por desconhecer bons